# How to split column to multiple columns with some features?

Tags: regex, pandas, split

I have a column like this

```
col1  
(0,0):19,(1,1):155  
(0,0):13,(0,1):32,(1,1):34  
(0,0):56,(1,0):43,(1,1):38  
(0,0):67,(0,1):45,(1,0):98,(1,1):70
```

and I would like to split it into four columns:

```
(0,0)    (0,1)    (1,0)    (1,1)  
19        0        0       155  
13        32       0       34  
56        0        43      38  
67        45       98      70
```

I have try `col.str.split(',\s*(?![^()]*\))',expand=True)` but can only get:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4  
(0,0):19    (1,1):155    NAN    NAN  
(0,0):13    (0,1):32     (1,1):34    NAN   
(0,0):56    (1,0):43     (1,1):38    NAN  
(0,0):67    (0,1):45     (1,0):98   (1,1):70
```

I was wondering if there is a way get what I show above? Thanks a lot!
Kun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract the digits after `(0,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(1,0)` and `(1,1)` and then drop the `col1` column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['(0,0):19,(1,1):155','(0,0):13,(0,1):32,(1,1):34','(0,0):56,(1,0):43,(1,1):38','(0,0):67,(0,1):45,(1,0):98,(1,1):70']})
df['(0,0)'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'\(0,0\):(\d+)', expand=False).fillna(0)
df['(0,1)'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'\(0,1\):(\d+)', expand=False).fillna(0)
df['(1,0)'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'\(1,0\):(\d+)', expand=False).fillna(0)
df['(1,1)'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'\(1,1\):(\d+)', expand=False).fillna(0)
df = df.drop(columns = ['col1'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  (0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (1,1)
0    19     0     0   155
1    13    32     0    34
2    56     0    43    38
3    67    45    98    70
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I also thought about doing it in this separate way!

Comment: @KunFang It is most convenient when your data is not that regular. Also, you may later adapt it to more complex cases if any. Note that Quang's code worked for me.

Comment: Understand~ weird, I tried it in my real data but show some error like this:File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 811, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 817, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1

Comment: @KunFang Then, I'd say your posted data is too simplified.

Comment: My mistake, I input '.' instead of ',' when I typed (',\s*(?![^()]*\))',expand=True), the Quang method also works!

Comment: @KunFang Yes. Still, `,\s*(?![^()]*)` regex is a workaround rather than a solution, it only works in cases where for every `)` there is a matching `(`. I think my approach is more flexible.

Comment: Agree, your solution is a more general solution for the complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

My approach with double `str.split` and `stack/unstack`:

```
(df.col1.str.split(',\s*(?![^()]*\))', expand=True)
   .stack().str.split(':',expand=True)
   .set_index([0], append=True)
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)[1]
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
0 (0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (1,1)
0    19     0     0   155
1    13    32     0    34
2    56     0    43    38
3    67    45    98    70
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I get a KeyError: 1 message.

Comment: Sorry I find a typo that the result I get the error...You approach also works! Thanks again!